# How do to Petapoco joins

Tags: petapoco

I've tried to follow the documentation on the Petapoco site as best I can with no luck.

I've got a `Customer` poco which I've modified to take a `List<Order> Orders {get; set;}`. I'd like to query customers and include their associated orders within each customer object.

```
using (var db = new Database("NorthWind"))
    {
        var sql = Sql.Builder
            .Select("*")
            .From("Customers customers")
            .LeftJoin("Orders orders").On("customers.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID")
            .OrderBy("customers.CustomerID");

        return db.Fetch<Customer, List<Order>, Customer>(
                     (c, o) => { c.Orders = o; return c; }, sql);
    }
```

The customer data always gets returned, but Orders is always empty. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.LeftJoin` seems like you have orders without customers. Why not use  an `.InnerJoin`. By using `(c, o) => { c.Orders = o; return c; }`, you are joining a collection to an object which I don't think is possible.

Modify you syntax to the following:

```
 return db.Fetch<Customer, Order, Order>(
               (c, o) => { o.Customer = c; return o; }, sql);
```

which will return orders and their related customers. I am assuming you have a customer property in the order object.

Comment: Actually I have a customer object with a list of orders (property). I was able to make this work by adding the order to the list rather than assigning.